# why Exception or Error not generated when no main method found?

Tags: java, program-entry-point

Ok just for sake knowledge , I tried below cases (Assume that Class A and B are in same package)

**ClassA**

```
public class ClassA {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println("A");
  }
}
```

**ClassB**

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("B");
  }
}
```

executing above `ClassB` it will produce output of `B` now after below change in classB

**ClassB**

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA {
   //blank body
}
```

If I compile and run in `terminal` it gives me output `A` that was totally surprising as it should had given `NoSuchMethodError` as no main method was their so kindly explain the weird behavior ?

**Note**: Many answers contains `Override` word please use `hiding` as we cannot override static methods in java.

Comment: There is no `static` method overriding, but there is **hiding**. In the first case, `ClassB` hides the `main` method from `ClassA`. In the second case `ClassB` does not hide the `main` method so the one from `ClassA` is called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first case, you're hiding the `main` method since you're defining a new one in the subclass, in the second case you didn't you'll inherent `A`'s main.

See [The Java™ Tutorials - Overriding and Hiding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html):

> If a subclass defines a `static` method with the same signature as a
>   `static` method in the *superclass*, then the method in the *subclass* **hides** the one in the *superclass*.

Comment: we cannot override static methods as java says :)

Comment: @BhargavModi Indeed, override is a bad word. Fixed.

Comment: @Maroun Maroun, this is what I proved with my classes.
@ Boris the Spider; please try to execute.

Answer (score 2):

In Java subclasses inherit all methods of their base classes, including their static methods.

Defining an instance method in the subclass with the matching name and parameters of a method in the superclass is an override. Doing the same thing for static methods *hides* the method of the superclass.

Hiding does not mean that the method disappears, though: both methods remain callable with the appropriate syntax. In your first example everything is clear: both `A` and `B` have their own `main`; calling `A.main()` prints `A`, while calling `B.main()` prints `B`.

In your second example, calling `B.main()` is also allowed. Since `main` is inherited from `A`, the result is printing `A`.

Answer (score 0):

`public static void main(String[] args)` is just a method which you inherit from `A` in second case.